# Magento 1.9 Warning: require_once and Fatal error: require_once

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

Anyone, can you help me how to solve this?

> Warning: require_once(/srv/app/Mage.php): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory in /srv/public_html/abstract.php on line 85
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/srv/app/Mage.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
> /srv/public_html/abstract.php on line 85

Comment: Please give an absolute path and check for the proper permission of the file.

Comment: It is something like you have `Mage.php` are not available into `app` folder

Comment: What is your document root und where have you put which Magento files?